# Directional derivatives in JModelica FMUs

Tags: modelica, fmi, jmodelica

How can I enable directional derivatives in JModelica FMUs?

I couldn't find any information about that compiler flag.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directional derivatives are not available from JModelica.org generated FMUs and it is not planned to add it. It will though be added to the commercial tool OPTIMICA Compiler Toolkit which is based on JModelica.org

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm interested in OPTIMICA FMI features. Do you think that it's suitable for real-time, large-scale, fluid problems?

Comment: Ah interesting, has JModelica.org always been [Open Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_core)/feature-limited like this?